# JSON.parse fallback for undefined array to avoid exception

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, fallback

I'm parsing my array and everything is OK if it is defined:

```
JSON.parse(myArray);
```

However I get an exception in case if myArray is undefined.

What is the best fallback for it, is there anything better than this:

```
JSON.parse(myArray || '[]');
```

similar like we first verify the object to avoid an exception if undefined

```
if (obj) {
//do something with obj.something
}
```

So, is there anything shorter than

```
JSON.parse(myArray || '[]');
```

Thank you.

Comment: That seems pretty short as it is.

Comment: That's pretty much as good as you'll get short of modifying the lib function to check undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current method works just fine as well. I don't really see a reason to change it but if you feel you need to two options come to mind:

First, you could initialize `myArray` with it defaulted to an empty array before it gets its values assigned.

```
var myArray = '[]';
```

Otherwise if `myArray` is a parameter passed to a method you are parsing it from, you can default it in the arguments section.

```
function dosomething(myArray = '[]') {
    JSON.parse(myArray);
}
```

Comment: right, but it should be `myArray = "[]"`, not just `[]`